# Scripting foreign keys from sys tables -- struggling with keys that have multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi Everyone and thanks in advance.

I've been trying to script foreign keys from my existing database and am having problems with keys that reference multiple columns.

The script I'm using is below:

```
    SELECT
    'FOREIGN_KEY' as KeyType,'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) +
    ' WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ' + '[' + OBJECT_NAME(f.object_id) + 
    ']' + ' FOREIGN KEY ([' + col_name(fc.parent_object_id,fc.parent_column_id) + 
    ']) REFERENCES ' + OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) + 
    ' ([' + COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,fc.referenced_column_id) + ']) ALTER TABLE ' + 
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + 
    OBJECT_NAME(f.object_id) + ']' as result
    FROM 
       sys.foreign_keys AS f
    INNER JOIN 
       sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
      ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN 
       sys.tables t 
         ON t.OBJECT_ID = fc.referenced_object_id
    WHERE 
       OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) = @TableName
```

This will return the desired foreign keys but as stated above I'm having problems with the following results:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreatmentPlanItems] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TreatmentPlanItems_TPNumber] FOREIGN KEY([PatientCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TreatmentPlans] ([PatientCode]) ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreatmentPlanItems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TreatmentPlanItems_TPNumber]  


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreatmentPlanItems] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TreatmentPlanItems_TPNumber] FOREIGN KEY([TPNumber]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TreatmentPlans] ([TPNumber]) ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreatmentPlanItems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TreatmentPlanItems_TPNumber]
```

The output I need should be the following:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreatmentPlanItems] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TreatmentPlanItems_TPNumber] FOREIGN KEY([Patientcode],[TPNumber]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TreatmentPlans] ([Patientcode],[TPNumber]) ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreatmentPlanItems] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TreatmentPlanItems_TPNumber]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a code sample, I hope you can adopt it to your needs:

```
declare @tName sysname;
set @tName = 'dbo.TableName';

with vPKColumns as (
    select c.object_id, c.column_id, c.name, ixc.key_ordinal
    from sys.key_constraints pk
        join sys.index_columns ixc on ixc.object_id = pk.parent_object_id and ixc.index_id = pk.unique_index_id
        join sys.columns c on c.object_id = pk.parent_object_id and c.column_id = ixc.column_id
    where pk.parent_object_id = object_id(@tName) and pk.type = 'PK'
),
vFKs as (
    select
        quotename(fk.name) as name,
        fk.parent_object_id,
        fk.object_id,
        case
            when fk.delete_referential_action_desc collate database_default = 'NO_ACTION' then NULL
            else ' on delete ' + replace(lower(FK.delete_referential_action_desc) collate database_default, '_', ' ')
        end as onDelete,
        case
            when fk.update_referential_action_desc collate database_default = 'NO_ACTION' then NULL
            else ' on update ' + replace(lower(FK.update_referential_action_desc) collate database_default, '_', ' ')
        end as onUpdate
    from sys.foreign_keys fk
    where exists (
            select 1
            from sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                join vPKColumns pkc on pkc.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id and pkc.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
            where fkc.referenced_object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        )
)
select
    'alter table ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + '
    with nocheck add constraint ' + fk.name + ' foreign key (' + stuff(
            (select ', ' + quotename(c.name)
            from sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                join sys.columns c on c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id and c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id and c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
            where fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
            order by fkc.constraint_column_id
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') + ') references ' + @tName + ' (' + 
        stuff(
            (select ', ' + quotename(pkc.name)
            from vPKColumns pkc
            order by pkc.key_ordinal
            for xml path(''), type).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,'') + ')' +
        isnull('
        ' + onDelete, '') +
        isnull('
        ' + onUpdate, '') + ';
GO
alter table ' + quotename(s.name) + '.' + quotename(t.name) + '
    check constraint ' + fk.name + ';
GO'
from vFKs fk
    join sys.tables t on t.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
order by s.name, t.name, fk.name;
```